# when searching from some pages it redirects to homepage

Tags: magento

I have a Magento store website - from some pages such as the Cart or the Account Login page, when a customer uses the search box it simply redirects them to the homepage. When searching from any other page it works just fine.
Any idea what the issue may be?
Many thanks.

Comment: Just leave it, it's fine

Comment: The question? It's off-topic for this site. It's not fine.